# How does npm draw the dependency tree?

Tags: node.js, console

npm does a nifty job of drawing a package's dependency hierarchy as a tree in the console:

```
$ npm ls
my-awesome-project@0.0.1
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├─┬ express@2.5.11
│ ├─┬ connect@1.9.2
│ │ └── formidable@1.0.11
│ ├── mime@1.2.4
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0
│ └── qs@0.4.2
└── uglify-js@1.2.6
```

How does npm do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

npm uses the Unicode [box drawing characters](http://unicodinator.com/#Block-Box_Drawing) (U+2500-2800) to draw the pretty lines of the tree.

To draw a similar tree in your own application, the best route is probably to use the same module that npm itself uses – [archy](https://npmjs.org/package/archy).

```
var archy = require('archy');
var s = archy({
  label : 'beep',
  nodes : [
    'ity',
    {
      label : 'boop',
      nodes : [
        {
          label : 'o_O',
          nodes : [
            {
              label : 'oh',
              nodes : [ 'hello', 'puny' ]
            },
            'human'
          ]
        },
        'party\ntime!'
      ]
    }
  ]
});
console.log(s);
```

Outputs

```
beep
├── ity
└─┬ boop
  ├─┬ o_O
  │ ├─┬ oh
  │ │ ├── hello
  │ │ └── puny
  │ └── human
  └── party
      time!
```

Answer (score 2):

For list your folders and files you can use tree-cli:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-cli

Just install:

```
npm install -g tree-cli
```

And use inside your folder:

```
tree -L 2, -d
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [console2](https://github.com/safebyte/console2) which does almost the same thing as `archy` does, but gives you useful additional features like improved stack traces, object inspection and more:

[image]

<kbd>[**Feature screenshot**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/safebyte/console2/master/media/help.png)</kbd>

<sup>*Full disclosure: **I'm the author of the repository***</sup>